# How can I pass data from a controller to another with id in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have two classes, `offers` and `order`. The `order` view contains the form to submission details.

All I need to do is pass offers data to order form

`Offers` class

```
public class Offers
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Offers_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Price { get; set; }

    public string? Image { get; set; }
    
    [AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" })]
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile? File { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

And this is my `Order` class:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string offer_Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public IActionResult Order(int id)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Order(int id, Orders orders)
{
    return View();
}
```

The `id` above comes form Offers.
Order View

```
<input asp-for="FullName" />

<input asp-for="PhoneNumber" />


<input asp-for="Price"  readonly/>  // here must the value come from Offers class

<input asp-for="Offers_name"  readonly />  // also here must the value comes from Offers class
```

any help will be Great
Thank you.

Comment: Is your problem solved ?  "pass data from a controller to another " What's another ? Do  you mean you have two controllers ?  pass offers data from one controller to another controller ? Or  ? Do you try to use TempData ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I need to do is pass offers data to order form.
> The id above comes form Offers

We can use the id to get the offers data  from offers. Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

controller:

```
 public IActionResult Order(int id)
 {
    
     var Offers = new  List<Offers>()
     {
         new Offers() {Id=1,Offers_name="ofn1",Price="p1"},
         new Offers() {Id=2,Offers_name="ofn2",Price="p2"},
         new Offers() {Id=3,Offers_name="ofn3",Price="p3"}
     };    //for test, you also can get Offers  use your way
     
     var result = Offers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);//use the id to get the offers data from offers
     var model = new Order();
     model.offer_Name = result.Offers_name;
     model.Price=result.Price;   
     return View(model);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Order(int id, Order orders)//Here you may want to use  Order class ,if not , what's your Orders class ?
 {
     return View();
 }
```

Order View:

```
@model Order

<form  method="post">
    <input asp-for="FullName" />

    <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" />


    <input asp-for="Price" readonly />  

    <input asp-for="offer_Name" readonly />  

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

result:

[image]